# Question about Google stock volume chart discrepancy

Tags: stocks

Let's take Disney stock for example:

Go to https://www.google.com/finance and search for Disney.

If I change the date range to 5 year, on October 20, 2023, the volume was 55 million.
But if I change the date range to 6 months, on October 20, 2023, the volume was 10 million.

And this occurs to every different stock I've looked at.
Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you "zoom out" to 5 years, the chart resolution goes from daily to weekly. You're seeing the volume for *5 days* worth of trading instead of 1.

You can also see this in the dates that are shown as you hover over the chart - they go from daily to every Friday (e.g. Oct 20, 2023, Oct 27, 2023)

You also see the effect when zooming in to 5-day data (every 30 minutes) and 1-day data (every minute).

The actual resolution may be different in different displays, but that's what I see when I see the chart in the search results.